# Max Range Sum Code Eval Challenge

Tags: java, algorithm, max

I am trying to solve Max Range Sum which is a code eval challenge which goes like this:

> Bob is developing a new strategy to get rich in the stock market. He wishes to invest his portfolio for 1 or more days, then sell it at the right time to maximize his earnings. Bob has painstakingly tracked how much his portfolio would have gained or lost for each of the last N days. Now he has hired you to figure out what would have been the largest total gain his portfolio could have achieved.
>
> For example:
>
> Bob kept track of the last 10 days in the stock market. On each day, the gains/losses are as follows:
>
> 7 -3 -10 4 2 8 -2 4 -5 -2
>
> If Bob entered the stock market on day 4 and exited on day 8 (5 days in total), his gains would have been
>
> 16 (4 + 2 + 8 + -2 + 4)

My input file contains :

```
5;7 -3 -10 4 2 8 -2 4 -5 -2
6;-4 3 -10 5 3 -7 -3 7 -6 3
3;-7 0 -45 34 -24 7
```

I am somehow getting zero as output for these three lines.
I tried debugging but did not get the issue.
Here is my code:

```
    package MaxRangeSum;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.Math.floor;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * @author kanua_000
 */
public class MaxRangeSum {
    
    public static int ret_cross = 0,ret_sum = 0;
    public static Integer leftsum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public static Integer rightsum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    public static int sum_cross = 0, maxleft = 0,sum_max = 0;
    public static int leftsum_subarray = 0;
    public static int rightsum_subarray = 0;
    public static int crosssum = 0;
   

    public static int max_crossing_subarray(int[] A, int low, int mid, int high) {
         
     
        int i = mid;
        while (i != low) {
            sum_cross = sum_cross + A[i];
            if (sum_cross > leftsum) {
                leftsum = sum_cross;
              //  maxleft = i;
            }
            --i;
        }

        
       // int maxright = 0;
        sum_cross = 0;
        int j = mid + 1;

        while (j != high) {
            sum_cross = sum_cross + A[j];
            if (sum_cross > rightsum) {
                rightsum = sum_cross;
             //   maxright = j;
            }
            ++j;
        }

        ret_cross = leftsum + rightsum;

        return (ret_cross);

    }

    public static int max_subarray(int[] a, int low, int high) {
        
        int i = 0,j = 0;
        int[] A = new int[50];

        if (low == high) {
            return (A[low]);
        } else {
            
            int mid = (int) (floor((low + high) / 2));
            
            while (i != mid) {
                ret_sum = ret_sum + A[i];
                if (ret_sum > leftsum_subarray) {
                    leftsum_subarray = ret_sum;
                }
                i++;
            }

            leftsum_subarray = max_subarray(A, low, mid);

            j = mid+1;
            
             while (j != high) {
                ret_sum = ret_sum + A[j];  
                if (ret_sum > rightsum_subarray) {
                    rightsum_subarray = ret_sum;
                  //  maxleft = i;
                }
                j++;
            }

            rightsum_subarray = max_subarray(A, (mid + 1), high);
            
            

            crosssum = max_crossing_subarray(A, low, mid, high);

            if ((leftsum_subarray >= rightsum_subarray) & (leftsum_subarray >= crosssum)) {
                return (leftsum_subarray);
            } else if ((rightsum_subarray >= leftsum_subarray) & (rightsum_subarray >= crosssum)) {
                return (rightsum_subarray);
            } else {
                return (crosssum);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        int n = 0, i = 0;

        int line1[] = new int[50];
        int line2[] = new int[10];
        int line3[] = new int[10];
        int line4[] = new int[6];

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\FresnoState\\CSCI 174\\MaxRangeSum.txt"))) {

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

                while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                    String digits = tokenizer.nextToken();

                    if (digits.contains(";")) {
                        digits = (digits.substring(2));
                    }

                    line1[i] = Integer.parseInt(digits);

                    i++;
                }
            }

        }

        int numOfChunks = 10;

        for (int k = 0; k < numOfChunks; k++) {
            line2[k] = line1[k];
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < line2.length; ++r) {
            System.out.print(line2[r] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        numOfChunks = 9;
        int j = 10;

        for (int l = 0; l <= numOfChunks; ++l, ++j) {
            line3[l] = line1[j];
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < line3.length; ++r) {
            System.out.print(line3[r] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        numOfChunks = 6;
        j = 20;
        for (int m = 0; m < numOfChunks; ++m, ++j) {
            line4[m] = line1[j];
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < line4.length; ++r) {
            System.out.print(line4[r] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        int line1_maxsum = max_subarray(line2, 1, 10);
        int line2_maxsum = max_subarray(line3, 11, 20);
        int line3_maxsum = max_subarray(line4, 21, 26);

        System.out.println(line1_maxsum);
        System.out.println(line2_maxsum);
        System.out.println(line3_maxsum);

    }

}
```

Comment: How did you "*try debugging*"? Did you go step-by-step through your code?

Comment: I recommend having a read on [Kadane's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

Comment: Yeah, I went step by step and my breakpoints were while loops, return statements and function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the method max_subarray is doing since its such a mess, but if you want to add up the number in the line try to use this in the max_subarray method and you can work around it i guess.

```
public static int max_subarray(int[] a, int low, int high) {

    int theMiddle = (int) Math.floor(a.length / 2);
    int leftSum = addArray(a, 0, theMiddle);
    int rightSum = addArray(a, theMiddle, a.length);

    if(leftSum > rightSum){
        return leftSum;
    }else{
        return rightSum;
    }

}

public static int addArray(int[] a, int start, int end) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: In max_subarray, I am dividing the array into 3 parts- left,right and  middle. Then I am iterating the left subarray to find maximum value, same for right subarray and middle subarray. Middle subarray is denoted by cross in my code. After getting the maximum value of sum from left, right and middle subarray, I am checking which one is the largest and then returning it.

Comment: so for this input 5;7 -3 -10 4 2 8 -2 4 -5 -2
6;-4 3 -10 5 3 -7 -3 7 -6 3
3;-7 0 -45 34 -24 7 each line is divided into 3 parts or is each line a part? and if you are dividing each line into 3 parts how big is each part because its 10 numbers and it doesnt go evenly into 3 parts

Comment: I am diving each line into 3 parts. Parts are not equal, for first input line with 10 integers in it, left subarray has 5 elements and right has 5. Then the middle subarray has some overlapping values and the upper and lower index of this array is adjusted in maximum_cross_subarray function. In this function, max subarray is decided on the basis of its middle element in array.

Comment: check the edit, it finds the left and right total. now you just need to add it so it find the middle.

Comment: So assuming from the post 16 (4 + 2 + 8 + -2 + 4) was calculated by the 5 that was in the beginning of line one. so you just need to find the starting point.

Comment: That is just a demo of final answer...but we have to check all the possible combinations to get that answer.....one of the combinations results in 16 and the question description only gives the result as combination.

Comment: so for row 1. you would add these element in the [0-4], [1-5], [2-6], [3-7], [4-8], [5-9] and use the largest answer.

Comment: ok now i think i got it... first you have to sort the array. and get the largest 5 for row 1

Comment: if i sort the array for number one i get 25 as an answer. Im guessing it 5 consecutive numbers